# How to get product price from variable product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I done simple popup where you can see price of product with installment. It work fine. But on variable product it gives only the minimal price of product. Of course I want to get a price of product which I choose. Please help!

```
    <?php
       $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id());
       if(!empty($product)){
       $price = $product->get_price();

        $deadline = 12;
        $rate = 25;

        $rate_sum = ($price/ 100) * $rate;
        $total_sum = $price+ $rate_sum;
        $base_per_month = $total_sum / $deadline;
} else {
        echo "product is empty" ;
};
            
?>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content position-relative">
<div class="modal-header"><strong>Купить в рассрочку</strong></div>
<div class="modal-body">
<h3>Через MegaDream</h3>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col" style="width: 33%;">Оплата за месяц</th>
<th class="col" style="width: 33%;">Срок (месяц)</th>
<th class="col" style="width: 33%;">Общая сумма</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b id="month_credit" style="color: #fe4f19; font-weight: 800;"><?php echo round($base_per_month); ?></b></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><b style="color: #fe4f19; font-weight: 800;">12</b></td>
<td><b id="total_credit" style="color: #fe4f19; font-weight: 800;"><?php echo round($total_sum); ?></b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
По вопросам получения товаров в рассрочку, звоните по номеру <strong>+998(99) 351-71-40</strong>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #457f33; color: white;" href="tel:+998993517140" type="button">Позвонить</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable product prices are different because a variable product can have different variations prices, so you can get the minimal price and/or the maximum price (or a formatted price range):

```php
$product = wc_get_product( get_the_id());

if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) || ! empty( $product ) ) {
    
    // 1. Variable product (min and max)
    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        $price_min = $product->get_variation_price('min'); // Float number
        $price_max = $product->get_variation_price('max'); // Float number

        $formatted_price_range = $product->get_price_html(); // Html formatted price range
    }

    // 2. Single product
    elseif ( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        $price = $product->get_price(); // Float number

        $formatted_price = $product->get_price_html(); // Html formatted price range
    }
}
```

It should better work now.

Comment: Thank you for answer but it does not work with Variable product as you say